# Do focus events work for QDockWidget objects?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm having trouble getting the "focusInEvent" to work for a QDockWidget-derived class in PyQt4. I've hunted around and it seems that my reimplementation syntax of the event is correct, but my code in the event handler never gets executed (I set a breakpoint in the event code block but it never gets triggered). Here's what I've done:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class ToolWindow(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, parent = None):
        super(ToolWindow, self).__init__(title, parent)

         ...initialization code here...

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        ..do on-focus work here...
```

At runtime I'm setting focus to the dock by mouse-clicking on it. I'm clicking both on the dock window title bar and also within the dock client space, but nothing triggers the event. I click to other "ToolWindow" objects in my application and none of them fire the event when focused. Is this not the correct event to use for that? Also, I tried tabbing around but that didn't work either. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that many QWidgets have the [`focusPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) attribute in `Qt::NoFocus` mode, then according to [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum).

> **Qt::TabFocus**: the widget accepts focus by tabbing.
>
> **Qt::ClickFocus**:   the widget accepts focus by clicking.
>
> **Qt::StrongFocus**:  the widget accepts focus by both tabbing and clicking. On macOS this will also be indicate that the widget accepts tab focus when in 'Text/List focus mode'.
>
> **Qt::WheelFocus**:   like Qt::StrongFocus plus the widget accepts focus by using the mouse wheel.
>
> **Qt::NoFocus** : the widget does not accept focus.

So to activate the focus I recommend changing that property to **Qt::StrongFocus**.

```
class ToolWindow(QtGui.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, parent = None):
        super(ToolWindow, self).__init__(title, parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
```

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc, that did it.